# Refrescar un contenedor y no toda la página completa

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas tardes,

Tengo el siguiente contenedor:

```
     <div id="refrescachat" class="direct-chat-messages" style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">


        <?php
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usuario']);
        $sess = $_SESSION['id'];
        $chats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE de = '$user' AND para = '$sess' OR de = '$sess' AND para = '$user' order by id_cha desc");
        while($ch = mysql_fetch_array($chats)) { 

          if($ch['de'] == $user) {$var = $user;} else {$var = $sess;}
          $usere = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_use = '$var'");
          $us = mysql_fetch_array($usere);
        ?>


        <?php if ($ch['de'] == $user) { ?>
        <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
          <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"">
            <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left"><?php echo $us['nombre']; ?></span>
            <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right"><?php echo $ch['fecha']; ?></span>
          </div>
          <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
          <img class="direct-chat-img" src="avatars/<?php echo $us['avatar']; ?>"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
          <div class="direct-chat-text">
            <?php echo $ch['mensaje']; ?>
          </div>
          <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->

        <?php } elseif ($ch['para'] == $user) { ?>

        <!-- Message to the right -->
        <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
          <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
            <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right"><?php echo $us['nombre']; ?></span>
            <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left"><?php echo $ch['fecha']; ?></span>
          </div>
          <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
          <img class="direct-chat-img" src="avatars/<?php echo $us['avatar']; ?>" alt="Message User Image"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
          <div class="direct-chat-text" style="background-color: #96ad9e;">
            <?php echo $ch['mensaje']; ?>
          </div>
          <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->

        <?php } ?>


    <?php } ?>



      </div>
```

Ese código es referente a un chat y necesito que ese contenedor se actualice cada segundo, pero sin afectar otros contenedores por que si se actualizada cada segundo con el contenedor de escribir entonces borra el mensaje cada segundo y no podría enviar mensajes. Esto lo necesito por que el chat funciona mediante base de datos MYSQL pero no es asincrono.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la petición cada cierto tiemplo con `setInterval` e ir agregando los últimos mensajes del `chat`.

> NOTA: para la prueba se consulta hacia un API de prueba que retorna 10 usuarios de los cuales hacemos un `random()` para obtener el nombre al azar y simular mensajes nuevos.

Espero te ayude saludos.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
function chat(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {
    $(".chat").prepend('<li>'+data[Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0)) + 0].name+'</li>')
  });
}

setInterval('chat()',1500);
```

```css
*{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(198, 198, 198);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0,.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chat">
    
  </ul>
```

Comment: La verdad necesito es actualizar el div que contiene el chat, pero aplicar esta lógica en el momento no me queda tiempo. Si me puedes colaborar con mi petición se lo agradecería.

Comment: si va amigo voy a averiguar y lo agrego a la respuesta

Comment: puedes usar un `iframe` y re cargarlo cada cierto tiempo no lo recomendaría pero puede ser tu solución